# const unions as registry for callbacks with different signatures

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some hard time, figuring out what is wrong with this types

```js
const registry = {
  foo: {
    magic: (d: number) => d
  },
  bar: {
    magic: (d: string) => d
  }
} as const

type Registry = typeof registry

const registryMagic = <T extends keyof Registry > (type: T, magicArgs: Parameters< Registry[T]["magic"] >) => {
  registry[type].magic(...magicArgs) // this is the issue "magic: (d: never) => string | number
}

registryMagic("foo", [123])
registryMagic("bar", ["test"])
```

Here is the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGMHsDsGcBdSILygNoG94E8AOBTALlAHIBDEgGlACNiAiM2AE3oF9qs8jSaraGuXO044CDcOwC6oJhBgIAUMqhxEAJ3wBzAJYJ12UKgyLQoAGaRIxE2bMBbMrvDEAFM2LQArvZr51AJRGAHygzKagHBE0ZOo2EQ5OOi6g7sT6OtBaQcih4WZsimyysPJqymL4oABK2nrwBkZI3JDmoJq6+tgqChp1XQCySeBNADwAKqD4AB7w+NDMpQDW+NitNf0NhqGulcTj1I7OAILqWrDEAAqxZPb4c+qwoxudW2jjUmj0R8n0MsE5UK2dqbAxoSpSAB0P3Arkh8Jhp3OASKyg69QMQ2crnolkg9GoaAAjAAmADMUhR6MGwxxMXUBPQ9DmCD+ASAA)

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Other than the fact that you're passing an array of params as a single param? The issue is that TS can't follow arbitrary higher order type correlations. If you want to express this you need to carefully craft the types to be in a form accessible to the type checker, as described in detail in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Using that approach here gives you [this code](https://tsplay.dev/w21M4W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thank for the answer. your provided code does the trick. i adopted i slightly to be closer to my question. link follows...

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gJwKYHMCW0EE8YF4YDeAUDKTAGYggBchJZDAtgIbrC0AUAJrWAK6MARkgQBKPAD4YXeqQC+AGlkxBzBLWIMmrNOxjdamNGBTjcUmQzlE5MZhBihIUIkShYADkngAlVBihsPBh3LxByeGR0TCw3T28-aMCsAFlmD2CCGABtAGkYYxgAayQscN9-GIBdWgAFNWZGJCgRCAAeOESA7Dyq7IAiFjZ+qqlrUITK5Myc-MKSsoiumLSPGsIYId1OADo9nhhl5NXesykANxA0LhhbaydoGCjurFojoPxEKewAblcH2DPFY6YDBNr5JAADxaYC4DgW5XeWAkHAmtFyCk2IIAgggUBA3t9UulTpI6AwgclshMqjstsAOHs6Ti8RBxAB6dkhAAWGAKDig3O8GAgfG8gxBnAOYCQ5xEZxgRhMMAAPjB+EIRDZXJTsGk2Bx+pQQP1MdkAIwAJgAzFVRERdcSDf1VAhTTl+i1oCNREA

Comment: I'd be happy to write an actual answer but it has been quite a while since I asked the above question... do you know if you'll be more available if I post an answer? I don't want things to languish in a half-done state until I forget them.